How to prove $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)\otimes_{\Bbb Z}(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z) \cong\Bbb Z/d\Bbb Z$ when $n$ and $m$ have greatest common divisor $d$.
I have a question about tensor products. When $n$ and $m$ are positive integers with greatest common divisor $d$, how do I prove that: $$(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)\otimes_{\Bbb Z}(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z)\cong\Bbb Z/d\Bbb Z.$$
I have tried creating an isomorphism from scratch, or tried to prove that most elements of the tensor product are equal to zero in some way but I cannot figure it out.

Does this answer your question? Proof of $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/ \gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}$ (found via Tensor product of cyclic groups (as $\mathbb{Z}$-mod): why is $\mathbb{Z}{n} \otimes{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}{m} = \mathbb{Z}{(n,m)}$?, using the search engine https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=tensor+product+of+cyclic+groups)

I still doubt recalling this tool (elementary and obviously known to the OP, and not even mentionned in any of the various answers) was helpful. The whole difficulty was in these various abstract nonsenses.

Apologies, you are right both used it explicitely.
